# Let's play some Great ork Gods!

Tags: discussion, chat-event

Never heard of it? That's probably because it's still in its playtesting stages, but here's the run-down:

> **Great Ork Gods** is an indie role-playing game - an anarchic game of savage and violent Orks and the cruel and fickle hand of the Gods that watch over them. Grab a beer, a handful of d10s and get ready to stiff your mates, burn buildings, kill anything that moves and smash stuff for fun. http://www.greatorkgods.co.uk/

Designed by [Jack Aidley](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/7377/jack-aidley), Great ork Gods is a tongue-in-cheek role-playing game where you play as vicious marauding orks *and* as the gods that hate them. It hasn't left its playtesting stages, but it has [garnered some impressive (unsolicited) reviews](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=ork%20gods&Room=11&page=1&pagesize=50&sort=newest) from chatizens:

> [doppelgreener](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11?m=37165930#37165930) May 4 4:20 PM
>   @MadMAxJr Your table would enjoy Great Ork Gods.

> [BESW](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11?m=36870477#36870477) Apr 21 10:12 PM
>   (great-ork-gods is my group's go-to system for "We want a night of slapstick violence and sudden meaningless character death.")

> [Joel Harmon](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11?m=36250518#36250518) Mar 24 2:20 AM
>   [...] Great Ork Gods, wherein multiple deaths per session is totally expected

> [trogdor](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11?m=29308665#29308665) Apr 28 '16 7:36 AM
>   except stuff like Great Ork Gods, cause that whole system is built for you to have fun while several of your Ork characters die XD

> [Sandwich](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11?m=25582260#25582260) Nov 21 '15 3:49 AM
>   I've heard that Great Ork gods is a blast to play

---

The [rules](http://www.greatorkgods.co.uk/) are simple enough to pick up as we go along, and are a whopping 9 pages long (7 if you skip the intro and sample scenario).

Place your suggestions for the schedule and run time in the comments. I'll see you then!

Comment: You'll also need to gather expressions of interest for people who would like to play. I suggest you update this question to request expressions of interest by some means. Bear in mind up to half may not turn up. We've found that GoG can work fine with just 3 players + GM by the way, and coincidentally that means approximately 7 people expressing interest means you have at minimum a solid game.

Comment: I'm interested, 1200 GMT is a *little* early for me, but I can swing it, and for future readers I can attest that @daze is an engaging and creative chat-GM.

Comment: I am also interested, but I work 1300-2200 GMT on weekdays. The ideal for me would be 1400 GMT on a weekend.

Comment: I'd love to play this one, and the time should work OK for me.

Comment: @doppelgreener perhaps a CW answer to express interest?

Comment: @Miniman I'd be ok with moving it a bit later, around 1400, to accommodate Oblivious Sage and nitsua60. The game will have to wrap up after 2 hours, though. Is that fine with you?

Comment: @daze413 Yep, that'd work for me.

Comment: Changed the date to give a little more time for expression of interest to sink in. New date is July 18.

Comment: @doppelgreener As I said, I can do 1400 on a week*end*. On a week*day* like the 18th my availability is more like 2300-0300 GMT, so I won't be able to make this first game.

Comment: @OblivioisSage Ok, didn't see that. Of course do whatever works for you. I'm hoping there will be a weekend game too. :)

Comment: Has anyone who has tried this also played *snit smashing* or *snits revenge?*

Comment: "It hasn't left its playtesting stages"... *checks release date*... hmmm..... I really should sort that out, shouldn't I?

Comment: I would love to get in on the next round of this, if you run another one! Tag me so I actually see it (hopefully in time :P)

Answer (score 4):

### Game 1: July 18, 2017 - 14:00-16:00 GMT +0

Great success! We [steam-cleaned some socks](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38853673#38853673), developed a [fear of water](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38854130#38854130), among other things.

[Full transcript of the game here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38851028#38851028).

---

**GM:** daze413
**Player count**: 3-7 (excluding GM)
**Venue**: [The Back Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13/the-back-room-live-tabletop-games)
**Run-time**: 2 hours

I suppose I should talk about what I expect from players? I've run GOG a couple of times, and it worked best when I let the players take the reins, so my main job as GM will only be to describe the situation, and judge which god should apply for a particular action.

**Register for this chat event in [The Back Room's event page](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/13/the-back-room-live-tabletop-games?tab=schedule)**