# Only D&D on this Stack?

Tags: support, game-systems

Sorry, I'm new to SE so don't hate me if this is a painfully newb question. I love RPG's but dislike D&D.  This Stack is called role-playing games, but from what I can tell it is 95 % D&D.

**Is there a better Stack for my ilk?**

Comment: By "group", do you mean Stack? In other words are you asking if there is a better Stack site to go to for RPGs that has less D&D? Also, is there a reason you tagged your question GURPS?

Comment: Welcome to RPG stack!  This would seem to be more of a meta question.  Perhaps we should shift it there?

Comment: Howard Johnson is right! (Well actually, @BenBarden is right).  Flagged to have the mods move this to meta.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose Yes, by group I mean Stack. I tagged it as gurps because I was required to tag as something, had limited time, and that was the first suggestion on mobile when I typed in "rpg".

Answer (score 30):

#### Your percentages are off, but you can ignore the [*dnd*] and [pathfinder] tags.

[This link](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/interesting-topics) tells you how to ignore a tag.

I find about 17,500 tags for D&D (and over 10K for the current edition) and roughly 5750 for Pathfinder

Out of 30,000 tags, not quite 95%.

You can also use the search to look for tags for only games that interest you, such as the [GURPS] tag.  I just did a quick tag search for GURPS [and came up with this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gurps).  (I also note that World of Darkness has 334 tagged questions).

#### Ask Away!

Ask a question about whatever role playing game you wish: we have experts on a great variety of games to include Fate, Savage Worlds, GURPS, Vampire the Masquerade, Traveller, Roll for Shoes, Pendragon, Feng Shui, Seventh Age, Dungeon World, Starfinder, and many others.

None of the other gaming stacks handle role playing games as well as this one, though for computer games, there is Arqade which covers the computer based RPG scene that isn't Table Top RPG's.

**Bottom Line**: no, there's isn't a better stack for what you are looking for if the topic is TTRPG's.

Comment: I think this answer would be improved if it included the fact that there is no other stack where an RPG question would do better than here. Though it's just occurring to me that there's an invisible CRPG/TTRPG split at play, too....

Comment: Ignoring DnD (and possibly also Pathfinder) completely leads to a bad experience if you're browsing the question lists because the tags are so popular. That's because each page contains a maximum of (default) 15 questions and then most (even all) of those questions will be hidden by completely ignoring the tag. ([This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1Qvl.png) is what I mean.)

Comment: @Laurel that's a fair point, I can suggest using tags for rather than tags against.

Comment: @nitsua60 done as requested.

Answer (score 13):

## RPG SE is a general RPG site

RPG SE is not a D&D-only site. Check out the [topic guidance page](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Role-playing Games Stack Exchange is for expert Q&A by and for players and gamemasters of tabletop role-playing games. If you play or run Dungeons & Dragons, Dogs in the Vineyard, Shadowrun, World of Darkness, FATE, or any of the thousands of other pen-and-paper RPGs (including LARPs), and need answers to your questions (or would like to answer questions about these games), this is the place for you.

[Popular tags](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=popular) include non-D&D systems like FATE, World of Darkness, Dungeon World, and Savage Worlds. If you're browsing or filtering by tag, you may also want to look at the [system-agnostic](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-agnostic) tag to see questions that don't directly tie into a specific game's playstyle and mechanics.

To my knowledge, the site's most dedicated users generally have experience with multiple systems.

## There sure are a lot of D&D questions here

You're not wrong about this. We talk about this issue from time to time on Meta, to try to make sure the site remains a useful place for non-D&D questions and answers. [Here is one such recent discussion](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7278/dungeons-and-dragons-is-dominating-the-site-in-terms-of-page-views/7293#7293).

Essentially, both these things are known to be true:

1. D&D is a huge part of the hobby.
2. D&D generates a lot of questions that fit the site's Q&A (not discussion) format pretty well, and a lot of new players' questions will be expressed in D&D-specific terms.

This means a general-RPG site with RPG SE's structure and footprint is likely to always have a ton of D&D-specific content. For the most part, we've accepted this as something to build on rather than worry about; thoughtful efforts to improve the site's experience for non-D&D players are always welcome, though!

(I don't play D&D.)

Answer (score 12):

The quantity of questions here reflect the relative popularity of various RPGs in the hobby. However there are knowledgeable people for many different RPG including the Dungeon Fantasy RPG and GURPS like myself.

Steve Jackson Games the publisher of the Dungeon Fantasy RPGs has [an active forum](http://forums.sjgames.com) and fan community. But again you will get [answers to GURPS](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gurps) and Dungeon Fantasy questions here.

Comment: I disagree with the assessment that the quantity of questions reflects the popularity of RPGs without further qualifiers. DnD's presence is plausibly boosted by a variety of factors in addition: it has a rich collection of lore to ask about, hard rules that cause lots of confusion, a character optimization dimension... and in addition, it's popular among *beginners*, who tend to encounter more problems in proportion than more experienced players.

Answer (score 4):

You are on the best Stack for RPGs. We are the only Stack that deals with tabletop RPGs and while we do get a lot of questions on D&D we have expertise in a great many different systems. Either way, there are really no other options as far as Stacks go. [As @KorvinStarmast says](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8642/only-dd-on-this-stack/8644#8644), you can easily block D&D tags so you won't ever see those questions if you don't want to.