# I just showed up here. Should I be somewhere else if I play other RPGs more than D&D?

Tags: support, game-systems

Seems like in name 'role-playing games SE' is as such, but by the numbers this is really D&D (and mostly 5E) SE.

I've seen this happen before on other sites (Usenet even), where the most obviously-named outlet for a hobby is kind of about the most currently-profitable aspects of that hobby, and enthusiasts sometimes need to use a different one.

1. First: I don't want to bother y'all; should I just plain be on another SE?
2. Second: If not, is there anything like the ability to filter questions by relevant game?

Comment: Related: [Dungeons and Dragons is dominating the site in terms of page views](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7278/52137), [Only D&D on this Stack?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8642/52137) (actually, does this answer your question?), [How can I find questions that don’t require system-/setting-specific knowledge to answer?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11480/52137)

Comment: I'll take a look at these links.  If I may, what made you 'comment' instead of 'answer', what's the etiquette there?

Comment: Well, I'm just linking you some extant questions on the same topic. Answers should be more than that, and if one of those does resolve (/answer) the question, we'll just close it as a dupe (and such dupe pointers are a good thing, to help others find where the information is).

Comment: OK, the way I see it, these links together do answer both aspects of my question: 
* no, there is no more appropriate SE for me.
* yes, I can filter posts, and it appears that 'tags' are the preferred way to do that

Thank you!

Comment: Is there something you’ve observed other than the prevalence of d&d questions that could lead someone to believe this was “d&d.stackexchange”, so to speak?

Comment: No, that prevalence is the only thing I observed; it did make an impression on me, though!  (9:1 ratio of Q's about one product to Q's about *all others combined*)

Comment: There's also our [main chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/trpg-general-cha) room, where we discuss all sorts as well as plenty of non-D&D games. Swing by if you haven't already :D

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### Our site is for all* tabletop role-playing games, not just D&D 5e.

It is true that D&D 5e questions seem to dominate the questions on our mainsite (Role-Playing Games StackExchange) for the past few years. The game is popular and its rules contain many ambiguities, therefore there are many users asking many questions about it.

However, our stack is for all* tabletop role-playing game systems. We also have questions that are not specific to any system, and deal with social issues and broader techniques.

* *(There are some exceptions, a few niche games that are considered too inappropriate to discuss and we don't want to give them publicity.)*

**How to filter questions according to game system:**

Questions can be sorted by tags, which are written in bracket notation. If you check the search bar on the mainsite, you should see some prompts for suggested tags. For example, searching `[fate]` will search for questions related to the Fate system.

You can also exclude specific tags from a search, with a hyphen prefix. Entering `-[dnd-5e]` will ignore all search results that are tagged as `[dnd-5e]`.

Lastly, you can customize filters to ignore certain tags. On the [main page](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/), look for a box titled "Ignored Tags". If you enter a list of tags here, then the mainsite will hide all questions with any of those tags.  You can also use wildcards to include a broad category of tags. For example, ignoring `[*dnd*]` should hide most Dungeons & Dragons questions from your display.

Comment: All these answers are good, but this one is the most complete about the tag system, which I especially appreciate

Answer (score 11):

#### You're welcome here no matter what tabletop RPGs you like to play*

By volume alone we do have a pretty disproportionate amount of questions about D&D, but that reflects the player base and the cohesion of that game system more than any sort of policy here.

**We badly want content relating to other games.** It can be surprisingly hard to encourage. There are a handful of other game systems I've played, but most of them have hardly any questions for me to answer and I happen not to have any pressing questions about them. There is less than *one entire page* of questions for *Stars Without Number*, despite it being a decade old, based on the D&D d20 system, and having a revised edition released several years ago.

(Can you guess what RPG I just bought a bunch of books for?)

Content can be filtered with game system tags, like [dnd-5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-5e), [l5r](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/l5r), [world-of-darkness](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-of-darkness), and similar.

If you like non-D&D tabletop RPG games, *please* consider sticking around!

---

* The asterisk indicates an issue with some explicitly, intentionally racist RPGs designed to introduce people to white supremacist ideologies which had a rash of questions here several years back. So there are *some* limits on what's allowed here, but it has nothing to do with D&D.

Answer (score 9):

## 99.9999% of all RPGs are ok here!

There are only a handful of games that we won't ever cater to. Those games are games that most players will not mention by their name. Their themes are so dripping with racism, misogynism, anti-semitism, and other non-tasteful topics, that merely mentioning the **names** of these games can upset players.

Just tag whatever game you ask about and if there is none, ask and we make one for you!

Comment: Thanks specifically for mentioning up-front that you don't want to answer what the forbidden games are; upon hearing some were forbidden that was my natural first question!

Comment: they are not *forbidden*, just so distasteful that reading anything in them is only a task of morbid curiosity and the list changes. as other games get made. Examples of topics: there are RPGs out there that by the rules feature *sodomizing whoever you beat in combat to death.* They are **the games that shall not be named**

Comment: @Trish doubly-split infinitive makes it unclear whether you are referring to rules that feature blunt-force killing someone in combat and then sodomizing them after they are dead (_sodomizing whomever you beat to death in combat_), or those that feature the victor in a non-lethal combat killing the vanquished through the act of sodomy itself (_sodomizing to death whomever you beat in combat_).  Either one is certainly distasteful, but they are different.

Comment: @Kirt sadly... *both*.

Comment: @Trish...Oh my!

Answer (score 1):

### You are welcome, but I don't want you to have false expectations.

You are welcome here as long as you follow our established rules, such as not propagating questions about white supremacist propaganda TTRPGs, and you follow our [code of conduct](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/conduct). You have many filtering tools at your disposal to filter via tags - see our [guidance on finding topics you are interested in](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/interesting-topics).

But you also have to ask yourself if we can provide the signal to noise ratio that .se networks pride themselves on if any given site of fifty entries shows you about five questions. You will not be able to [participate on some days](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11488/44723) nor [stay in the loop for site developments](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11452/44723) like someone who follows D&D, and D&D5e in particular. Many of our meta decisions reflect that we have been [88% D&D and umbrella for several years](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11453/44723).

So while you are welcome, if you are not interested in the D&D umbrella, I don't want you to have false expectations. Some active people spend a lot of effort on answering non-D&D questions and will go out of their way even beyond the generous help that people offer on .se websites e. g.  because of their interest in sharing their joy about the hobby with you, but using rpg.se when you don't want to interact with the D&D umbrella requires more effort and leaves you less room for participation.

Comment: Even obscure games like MAID get answers here - at times they even get more love than the generic D&D question because how *different* they are.

Comment: @Trish we are in agreement, see my last paragraph.